# Google Firebase I want to console log my firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Simple question I hope you good people can help me with.

I'm using Firebase and I can display my firebase data on the page using:

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('jumbotron/header');
dbRef.on('value', snap => container.innerText = snap.val());
```

But when I try to: `console.log(dbRef)`
It displays as an object. I think this is because the reference is a URL. How can I console.log or print my firebase data as a string and eventually place it on my page using vanilla javascript. I can't find the solution in the FB documentation and there aren't any tutorials on the Google FB.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks, All

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the name implies `dbRef` is a reference to the data, it is not the data itself.

When you attach a listener to the reference with `on()`, you will get a *snapshot* of the data at that location. You can get the value from this snapshot and print it:

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('jumbotron/header');
dbRef.on('value', snapshot => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked. Beautiful. This helped me understand it a lot better. Answer marked as solved.